# Вывод цены товара

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, как скрыть старую цену товара при детальном просмотре товара?
Т.е. чтобы не выводилась зачёркнутая цена, вне зависимости от вида товара: вариативный или простой.
Как я понял, этот код $product->get_price_html() выводит две цены.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На выбор - есть такие функции вывода цены:

```
$_product->get_regular_price();
$_product->get_sale_price();
$_product->get_price();
```

Из названий понятно про первые две. Третья выводит активную цену.

Есть фильтр, с помощью которого можно поправить html-вывод из функции `product->get_price_html()`:

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', $price, $this );
```

Получить символ текущей валюты:

```
$currency_symbol = html_entity_decode( get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() );
```

Comment: > Из названий понятно про первые две. Третья выводит обе цены.

Comment: поправил ответ.

Comment: `<p class="price">get_regular_price <?php echo $product->get_regular_price(); ?></p>
<p class="price">get_sale_price <?php echo $product->get_sale_price(); ?></p>
<p class="price">get_price <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?></p>
     <p class="price">get_display_price <?php echo $product->get_display_price(); ?></p>
<p class="price">get_price_html <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>`

Comment: только этот код выводит две цены get_price_html()

Comment: Ну и что? Я дал прямые функции, из которых можно получить три варианта цены. Если надо, есть фильтр apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', $price, $this );

Comment: А как вывести вместе с текущей валютой?

Comment: $currency_symbol = html_entity_decode( get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() );

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54871/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-word).

Comment: > Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате

Comment: а почему здесь нельзя?

Comment: не приветствуется здесь простыни. Это автоматическое приглашение в чат